# App Engine to Cloud SQL PostgreSQL flask framework pg8000 driver error

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

Have tried google docs connection methods via unix socket and tcp, have tried changing from standard to flex application in app.yaml for app engine, application runs locally outside of gcp and is able to pull the form data accordingly.

The error that continues to arise is a pg800 driver error on my connection to postgres. I have yet to figure this out after trying for several days and several different configuration methods, including changing the driver to psycopg2 (which also errors out).

Each of the necessary API's are enabled, from I can see and it is authenticating using my default gcp account. In case that was the issue, have also tried enabling service accounts with necessary keys and necessary IAM privilege's (where I was also getting the driver error). Have listed code below, any help is GREATLY GREATLY appreciated....

I also have html flask templates that are rendered but don't think those would be problem related...

Thanks!

```
app.yaml
runtime: python37

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

```
__init__.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


def init_app():
    """Construct the core application."""
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')

    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        from . import routes  # Import routes
        db.create_all()  # Create sql tables for our data models

        return app
```

````
main.py

## IMPORTS
from __init__ import db
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from string import Template
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
import psycopg2
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, sqlalchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate, migrate
import json, operator
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import logging
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from apiclient.discovery import build
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

## INITIALIZE APP
DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__)

SCOPES=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '../perm/key-file'
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file( SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
accesstoken = creds.token


## CONFIGURATIONS
db_user = 'user'
db_pass = '123456'
db_name = 'baseballpitchers'
db_host = '104.196.132.156'
db_sock = '/cloudsql'
cloud_sql_connection_name = 'test-328103:us-east1:baseball'            

pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(

    # Equivalent URL:
    # postgresql+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>
    #                         ?unix_sock=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
        drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
        username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
        password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
        database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
        query={
            "unix_sock": "{}/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432".format(
                db_sock,  # e.g. "/cloudsql"
                cloud_sql_connection_name)  # i.e "<PROJECT-NAME>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>"
        }
    )
) 

Session = sessionmaker(bind=pool)
session = Session()

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

class BaseBall(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'baseballpitchers'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    era = db.Column(db.Float())
    ip = db.Column(db.Float())
    sop9 = db.Column(db.Float())
    bbp9 = db.Column(db.Float())
    whip = db.Column(db.Float())

    def __init__(self, name, era, ip, sop9, bbp9, whip):
        self.name = name
        self.era = era
        self.ip = ip
        self.sop9 = sop9
        self.bbp9 = bbp9
        self.whip = whip

    def asdict(self):
        return {'name': self.name, 'era': self.era, 'ip': self.ip, 'sop9': self.sop9, 'bbp9': self.bbp9, 'whip': self.whip}
           

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('pubtemp/parent.html')  


@app.route('/Player_Selection', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def data():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        
        fname = ''
        fera = request.args.get("ERA")
        fip = request.args.get("IP")
        fsop9 = request.args.get("SOp9")
        fbbp9 = request.args.get("BBp9")
        fwhip = request.args.get("WHIP")

        sname = BaseBall.name != fname
        sera = BaseBall.era < fera
        sip = BaseBall.ip > fip
        ssop9 = BaseBall.sop9 > fsop9
        sbbp9 = BaseBall.bbp9 < fbbp9
        swhip = BaseBall.whip < fwhip
        
  
        var = session.query(BaseBall).filter(sname, sera, sip, ssop9, sbbp9, swhip).all()
        final = [p.asdict() for p in var]
        p1 = sorted(final, key=lambda i: i['name'])
        
    return jsonify(p1)


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return """
    An internal error occurred: <pre>{}</pre>
    See logs for full stacktrace.
    """.format(e), 500
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)```
````

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).